# Data over mobile network switching on behind my back - what could be doing it and how to stop?

Tags: security, malware

Alcatel OneTouch 983, Android 2.3.7

I normally have "Enable data access over mobile network" switched off so as not to drain my phone credit, only switching it on when I want to do something quick on the Internet and don't have wi-fi access where I am.

However, a few days ago, for no apparent reason at all, this setting began switching on at intervals without me doing anything.  Tried switching my phone off and on, tried killing most of my running services, has made no difference.  Generally, a few times a day I find that it has switched on.

Have installed AVG Antivirus Pro and it found nothing.

Any clue of what it could be that's doing it - and more importantly, how to get rid of whatever it is?  I hate to imagine how much of my phone credit it has drained!

Comment: What other apps do you have installed?

Comment: Agree with @1990clb it is important to **mention** at least the **apps** that you installed or changed around the time the problem started or other setting that you may have changed. Another general piece of advice is that when it comes to **Android**, Antivirus softwares are misleading as there is **no concept of viruses** in Android at the most there are badly coded apps and even apps designed to perform maliciously! Also **please mention if your device is rooted**

Comment: I don't remember installing anything new around the time the problem started.  Usually I update apps I installed when I'm told an update is available, but avoid updating system apps unnecessarily in order not to clog up the internal memory.

Comment: But the apps I have installed: 1Tap Cleaner, Adobe Reader, FastConnect (which I haven't managed to get to work), Mail.com, National Rail Enquiries, StopWatch & Timer, Wikipedia (which I might uninstall as it's no real improvement over the mobile version of the website), and various games (none of which have any reason to access the Internet except for when I choose to download new puzzles).

Comment: @reubenjohn And no, it isn't rooted.  What do the likes of AVG Antivirus for Android do, if not protect you against viruses?  Should it really be called AVG Antibadlycodedapp or AVG Antiappdesignedtoperformmaliciously?

Comment: @Stewart haha you don't seem convinced I am partially at blame since I hadn't provided any references so here is one by one of the most popular android *antiviruses* [Lookout-reference](https://www.lookout.com/resources/know-your-mobile/android-virus) specifically under the section **Is there really such a thing as an Android virus?** where they make it crystal clear. Another thing please reference the person when making comments so that they will be notified!

Comment: @Stewart Also none of the apps you mentioned seem suspicious especially since you said you hadn't installed anything around the time. I would suggest a system bug. Or a workaround would be to use an app that automatically controls the network state according to your customization (I suggest Juice defender whether you have such a problem or not)